# How to save vCARD using QR rawValue on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, barcode-scanner, vcf-vcard

I need to save to contacts if the QR code contains vcard. I'm using Google API vision to scan QR code. For contacts its provide a `rawValue`. How can I save it as a contact in android phone? [I used this method but it's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W4GC.png):

**Code**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(barcode.rawValue),"text/x-vcard"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: 1]